# How can *++argv[0] refer to different command line arguments?

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

So I was reading The C Programming language and came across a section where programs were now allowed to have arguments...
For example

```
find -x -n pattern
```

Here, `-x` means except.
`-n` means numbered lines...
and `pattern` is what it will look for, in another few lines of input.

Now they regard `find` as `*argv[0]`, `-x` and `-n` at `*++argv[0]`, and `pattern` as `*++argv[0]`. How does a computer know one arg from the other?

If 3 things are all equal to `*++argv[0]`, then they stay at `argv[1]`, but all of them??
Could anyone please explain in depth?

Comment: Note that `*++argv[0]` changes the value of pointer `argv`.

Comment: You should read what the `++` operator does.

Comment: google "what are argv and argc"

Comment: ++ is pre-increment operator. :) It changes the value of the pointer argv using C pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Guys, I know what argc, argv and post and pre increment/decrement operators are, but in a loop, everytime you do ++argv[0], won't you end up with the next char/ int? i.e, argv[1]...

Comment: The `[0]` doesn't get incremented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
argv[0] = program name = "find"
argv[1] = first argument = "-x"
argv[2] = second argument = "-n"
argv[3] = third argument = "pattern"
```

`argc` = 4, so you know there are no other arguments to process.

Don't be confused by the use of the pre-increment operator in expressions like `*++argv[0]`.  The arguments are passed in separate array elements.

When the shell executes your command, it uses whitespace to divide the command line
up into the program name and arguments and pass them to your program.  Sometimes you need to work around that by using double quotes, for example, if you need to deal with a file whose name contains embedded spaces:

```
mv some stupid filename sane_filename
```

This won't work because "some" "stupid" "filename" will be seen as separate arguments.
But you can do this:

```
mv "some stupid filename" sane_filename
```

to get a single argument with embedded spaces.

Comment: Ooh, so each argument is basically seperated by a space.. ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `++n` **preincrement** operator changes the variable it is applied to. The first time `++argv` is executed, indexing it at `0` actually points to element `1` of the *original* value `argv` had, the second time it points to element `2`, and so on.

Comment: What about it all being ++arv[0]... also, how does the computer know one argument from the other? 
They are all on one line, and are not seperated by commas...

Comment: The computer doesn't know. The shell tells it, when it runs the command.